# How to fix "GeoType" plugin does not exist

Tags: location

I'm following [this](http://savaslabs.com/2015/07/06/map-in-drupal-8.html) tutorial. I've installed the geofield module and all needed for it wo work. I finally manage to create a content type "Place" with a field of type geofield. When i then create a new content of type "Place", i get the following message on drupal 8.0.3:
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

> Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "GeoType" plugin does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->doGetDefinition() (line 57 of C:\wamp\www\drupal8\core\lib\Drupal\Component\Plugin\Discovery\DiscoveryTrait.php)

I'm using drupal 8.0.3
with geofield 8.x-1.0-alpha1
Note i also habe geoPHP enable.
Any idea how i can solve this issue?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in geofield, did you search the issue queue: https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/geofield?categories=All

Comment: Yea i looked up. But nothing to find there.

Comment: Try read this and other linked issues. It might help you. It is related to the module and this site can't help with module specific bugs. https://www.drupal.org/node/2535450

Comment: I believe the solution is in geoPHP module dev version.

Comment: I already read all of that. But there is none that deal with the problem.

Comment: Try using the development builds of both modules. Then if it still doesn't work create a new issue explaining in detail what you have tried, which versions you used and what errors you get after what steps. Module bugs or other incompatibilities do not fit the scope of this Q&A website and cannot be solved here, but should be addressed in the module's issue queue as per: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: This patch solved the problem:                                                                -  * @Plugin(
+ * @Constraint(
   *   id = "GeoType",
   *   label = @Translation("Geo data valid for geofield type.", context = "Validation"),
   * )

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was a bug report that should have been handled in the module's issue queue and that now is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Alfter some reading and searching, i finaly found a solution. Just go [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1957760#comment-10124388) and apply patch #10. It's just one change that need to be done in the GeoConstraint.php file in src/Plugin/Validation/Constraint/GeoConstraint.php. In line 14,7 change "@Plugin(" to "@Constraint("